# Ghosting using turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

When running my script the GIF or paint mark (both are included in my code) is generated in the centre of the screen for a brief second before it moves to its assigned location. Why? Shouldn't the `penup()` function fix this?

I'm trying to loop my GIF so it updates and tracks across my screen whilst keeping my other assets static.  Is this causing some sort of refresh problem?

I've tried `hideturtle()` but that hides what I've generated, not the original blip in the centre of my screen.

```
# Baikonur Cosmodrome

lat = 45.86
lon = 63.31
location = turtle.Turtle()
location.penup()
location.color('yellow')
location.goto(lon, lat)
location.dot(5)
location.hideturtle()
url = 'http://api.open-notify.org/iss-pass.json'
url = url + '?lat=' +str(lat) + '&lon=' + str(lon)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
result = json.loads(response.read())
over = result['response'][1]['risetime']
style = ('Arial', 6, 'bold')
location.write(time.ctime(over), font=style)
turtle.hideturtle()

def Spacestation_Tracking():

url = 'http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
result = json.loads(response.read())

location = result['iss_position']
lat = float(location['latitude'])
lon = float(location['longitude'])
print ('latitude: ', lat)
print ('longitude: ', lon)

#Draw the map and the ISS ontop of it the ISS will move to the go to coordinates
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(1980,1020)
screen.setworldcoordinates(-180, -90, 180, 90)
screen.bgpic('world3.png')
screen.register_shape('iss3.gif')
iss = turtle.Turtle()
iss.shape('iss3.gif')
iss.setheading(90)

iss.penup()
iss.goto(lon, lat)
time.sleep(5)
while True:
Spacestation_Tracking()
```

No error messages until I close the window, as there is no way to break the program currently. I was expecting a clean dot to appear at the coordinates given, and the GIF to move and refresh without reverting to the centre each time.

I am coding on Windows 10 using the Python for Windows download version 3.7.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The turtle will be visible as soon as `turtle.Turtle()` returns, the `penup()` is one step too late.  What I recommend instead is:

```
lat = 45.86
lon = 63.31

location = turtle.Turtle(visible=False)
location.penup()
location.color('yellow')
location.goto(lon, lat)
location.dot(5)
```

This eliminates the need for the `hideturtle()` call after `dot()` as the turtle is already hidden and the `dot()` method doesn't require the turtle to be visible.  Similarly, I would suggest:

```
iss = turtle.Turtle(visible=False)
iss.shape('iss3.gif')
iss.penup()
iss.setheading(90)
iss.goto(lon, lat)
iss.showturtle()
```

to hide all your turtle configuration and call `showturtle()` at the end to display the finished product.

However, it's hard to tell for certain as your example code isn't indented correctly, commands like:

```
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(1980,1020)
screen.setworldcoordinates(-180, -90, 180, 90)
screen.bgpic('world3.png')
screen.register_shape('iss3.gif')
iss = turtle.Turtle()
iss.shape('iss3.gif')
```

*don't* belong in a *loop* nor in a function that's called *repeatedly*.  They should be part of your setup code and only called *once*.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your information was clear and useful. The poorly indented code, was I think in part with my incorrect formatting of the question, so my apologies, and thanks for your corrections on that as well.